# DFS по графу runtime error на части тест кейсов

Tags: python, словари, dfs

В задаче дано прямоугольное поле NxM и K помеченных клеток. Клетки считаются соседями по стороне, но не по углам. Посчитать количество компонент связности.

N,M,K заданы в первой строке input.txt, затем идет K строк с парами значений координат помеченных клеток i,j. Решение ниже проходит большинство тест кейсов, но выдает runtime-error на некоторых. Система не выдает, какой именно runtime-error.

```
with open("input.txt") as f:
    inp = f.readlines()

line1 = list(map(int, inp[0].strip().split()))
N = line1[0]
M = line1[1]
K = line1[2]

#represent marked cells as a dictionary, key = cells, value = list of marked neighbors
dict_ = {tuple(map(int, x.strip().split())): [] for x in inp[1:]}

#collect neighbors
def get_neighbors(idx):
    i = idx[0]
    j = idx[1]
    ans = [(i - 1, j), (i + 1, j), (i, j - 1), (i, j + 1)]
    return ans

#add them to the graph
def add_neighbors(idx):
    neighbors = get_neighbors(idx)
    dict_[idx] = [x for x in neighbors if x in dict_.keys()]  # return(None)


def dfs_recursive(graph, vertex, visited, path):
    visited[vertex] = True
    path.append(vertex)
    for neighbor in graph[vertex]:
        if not visited[neighbor]:
            path = dfs_recursive(graph, neighbor, visited, path)
    return path


def conn_comps(graph):
    visited = {vertex: False for vertex in graph}
    comps = []
    for vertex in graph:
        if not visited[vertex]:
            path = []
            v_path = dfs_recursive(graph, vertex, visited, path)
            comps.append(v_path)

    return comps

#populate neighbors
for idx in dict_.keys():
    add_neighbors(idx)

ans = len(conn_comps(dict_))


FOUT = open("output.txt", "w")
FOUT.write(str(ans))
FOUT.close()
```

Ограничения:  1 <= N,M <= 10^5, N*M <= 10^8, 0 <= K <= min(10^5, N*M).

Comment: Возможно по глубине рекурсии вылетает, у питона в районе 1000 ограничение. Рекурсию лучше не использовать по возможности кроме как для учебных целей, лучше сделать например очередь и её обрабатывать.

Comment: Если проблема действительно с глубиной рекурсии, то можно попробовать `sys.setrecursionlimit`, но некоторые тестирующие системы не воспринимают данную команду.

Comment: спасибо, у меня примерно такие же мысли были, но сходу не придумал, как это легко протестировать. Интересно, что рекурсивное решение на с++ (не мое) вроде выбивает все тест кейсы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если что - вся проблема была в recursion limit. Достаточно переписать итеративно либо используя `sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)`.